# RewriteCond from iphone/ipad application

Tags: iphone, apache, ipad

In my apache, the config file looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^mysite.com [NC]
```

I build an iphone and ipad application and inside I put a safari browser.

How can I allow the safari browser of the application (only the application that I created) to access the image?

Comment: Can you make your app send some kind of custom HTTP header e.g. `X-APP: some app`?

Comment: I am using Apple browser - safari - and couldn't find a way to send any headers there.

Comment: do you mean that you have a WebView in your application and you want it to browse the site with different behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using iOS UIWebView this could be a solution:

You change the default user agent (here we are changing it to "UniqueAppUserAgent") sent by WebView by running this code once when your app starts

```
NSDictionary *dictionnary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"UniqueAppUserAgent", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionnary];
```

Then use the %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} as your condition

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} UniqueAppUserAgent
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you would like to send a request out of your app and specify an HTTP_REFERER so that your apache rule is activated.

You can do this by splitting the HTTP request to your server and the displaying of the HTML inside of your app. I.e.,

1. get the HTML out of your server by using an `NSURLConnection`; you can find many examples of using it on the web, here I want just to point out that you can specify a custom header for your request like this:

   ```
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
    [request setValue:@"mySite.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"HTTP_REFERER"];
   ```
2. once, you get the HTML from your request, you load it in your UIWebView by using         `- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL`:

   ```
   [webView loadHTMLString:myHtml baseURL:nil];
   ```

If you provide the code you have, in any case, it will be easier to help.